# MySQL Mostrar todos los datos a la IZQUIERDA de una tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

tengo el siguiente problema. Formulé una consulta SQL que me entrega datos de camiones que trabajan durante la **semana actual**, el problema es que necesito que se muestren todos los camiones, incluyendo los que no han trabajado durante la semana actual (con datos 0 por ejemplo). Solo logró obtener en la lista los equipos que trabajaron.

Los camiones están en la tabla **equipo e**

```html
SELECT e.id_equipo, 
e.sigla_equipo, 
sum(r.kmRipio_ruta + r.kmPav_ruta) as kms,
count(p.id_programa) as cantidad, 
sum(r.tarifa_ruta) as suma,
sum(r.tarifa_ruta) / (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(if(c.festivo=0, 1, 0)),0) as asignado
    FROM calendar c
    WHERE YEARWEEK(c.fecha) = 201842 AND c.fecha <= now() AND c.festivo = 0) as prod_turno,
AVG(r.hrsEfectivas_ruta) as hrsEfectivas,
AVG(r.kmRipio_ruta + r.kmPav_ruta) as distMedia,
e.meta_equipo * (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(if(c.festivo=0, 1, 0)),0) as asignado
             FROM calendar c
             WHERE YEARWEEK(c.fecha) = 201842 AND c.fecha <= now() AND c.festivo = 0) as meta_equipo,
e.meta_equipo * (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(if(c.festivo=0, 1, 0)),0) as asignado
       FROM calendar c
       WHERE YEARWEEK(c.fecha) = 201842) as meta_semanal
FROM equipo e
LEFT JOIN programa p ON e.id_equipo = p.id_equipo
LEFT JOIN ruta r ON r.id_ruta = p.id_ruta
LEFT JOIN base b ON b.id_base = p.id_base
LEFT JOIN estado_programa ep ON ep.id_estado_programa = p.id_estado_programa
WHERE ep.abrev_estado_programa IN ('FIN','AS','AO', 'CAR', 'SO', 'DES', 'SD') AND b.nombre_base = '$base' AND YEARWEEK(p.horarioOrigen_programa) = 201842
GROUP BY e.id_equipo
ORDER BY e.sigla_equipo ASC
```

Agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Con el planteamiento actual llevaría mucho tiempo comprender la consulta para responderte, te recomiendo leer como crear un [mcve] y luego editar tu pregunta con un ejemplo más sencillo.

Answer (score 0):

La solución era más simple.

Antes:
LEFT JOIN base b ON b.id_base = **p.id_base**

Despues:
LEFT JOIN base b ON b.id_base = **e.id_base**